# Hide input values from source code

Tags: php, forms

I'm using a very simple API with HTML parameters but I would like to hide (from the source code) the values from certain fields (like API username and password) and also to hide the form action value (that appears as a link on the Submit button).

Code example:

```
<form name="test" action="https://test.com/api.php" method="post">
<input name="user" type="hidden" value="test">
<input name="password" type="hidden" value="test">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Maybe adding the values in a php file?

Comment: Its better if you encrypt and then use in hidden input..

Comment: `hide the form action value ` please explain it clearly.If you dont specify action value the you can get the posted value in same page only

Comment: I would like to hide the link from the Submit button (to not show https://test.com/api.php) but obviously the form should work as it was not hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a PHP action file, redirect your form to this PHP file, fill up the user and password fields and use curl to post data from PHP and get data back from the other API .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have a code sample by any chance for this (I'm new to PHP)?

Comment: It would be quite hard to give you a sample without writing the entire file as you don't know PHP, but with a little googling, I've been able to find this tutorial on how to make post requests with curl http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post . In your PHP file, you'll have to handle user submitted data. I can provide you the official PHP basic tutorial on php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide form action or some fields value. Instead of hiding, you can encode and decode through the programming language.

This way provide you a better security.

Don't use any intermediate page because this takes some more time get result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery to update these fields after the page has loaded:

```
$('input[name="user"]').attr('value', username_str);
$('form[name="test"]').attr('action', url_str);
```

Although this will not hide the URL and Value from "View Source" after the page has loaded, It will prevent spiders from accessing you form (which is what you want, unless you know that someone is specifically trying to take advantage of your form.)

For added security, user ajax to sent the username to the page and a simple string encoding function on the server with a decoding function in the page's javascript.

here is a good example of a javascript decoder: http://www.mailtoencoder.com/