# How to hide the password character in html form?

Tags: php, html, forms, passwords

I want to echo $password to input field of form, because the form is be able to post the password to do something later.
I don't want display any password character in html source code.
How to do that?
Thanks a lot!

```
<?php

 //Don't display password character in html source code... How?
 echo '<input type="password" name="pwd" value="'.$password.'">';

?>
```

Comment: You can't. You shouldn't be doing this anyway. The user should be required to enter it again for security purposes. At least that's how I would do it. If you must save it, store it in a SESSION but this still has security flaws.

Comment: *"I don't want display any password character in html source code."* - Why would you want to do that in the first place, don't do this and there's no reason to. It's a "I want my cake and eat it too", you can't.

Comment: What is the idea behind "hiding" the password from the html source? If an end user has access to the browser it's a trivial matter to get the password in the clear by changing the input type to text.

Comment: Don't pull in the password, make the user enter it in.

Comment: To add, the only way it would show up in HTML source, is if it's already been fetched from a given source, so again, don't do this because you're only asking for trouble. Having a pre-populated password means that it's been stored in plain text, or has been saved as plain text first in a seperate table/source and then compared with at a hashed level; a major security flaw.

Comment: Here, see this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/22352279/ which one of the answers contains this link http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Answer (score -1):

use this to hide your password

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Password" name="password"/>
```